# "Expected class or package" error with SharedPreferences in new method

Tags: android

I have no idea what's the problem here, Android Studio tells me for "sharedPref" in the if part the error "Expected class or package":

```
package xyz.myapp;
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
...
}

public void deleteobjects(View view) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String identification = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.IDENTIFICATION);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("xyz.myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Map<String,?> map = sharedPref.getAll();
    for (Map.Entry<String,?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().startsWith(identification + "_") || entry.getKey() == identification ) {
            sharedPref.Editor.remove(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
}
```

Comment: Have you imported, import android.content.SharedPreferences;

Comment: @ViVekH: Yes, it's imported..

Comment: if the problem is sharedPref.Editor , you should use sharedPref.edit().

Comment: You need to call `edit()` on a `SharedPreferences` to get an `Editor`. You don't use the class directly. You also need to `commit()` or `apply()` after the `remove()` for the changes you take. Also, you want to do the `String` comparison in the `if` with `equals()`, not `==`.

Comment: Thanks, edit() instead of Editor did it! I wasn't aware of that. And ok, i will use equals() instead of ==.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this line:

```
sharedPref.Editor.remove(entry.getKey());
```

and replace it with:

```
sharedPref.edit().remove(entry.getKey()).apply();
```